# how to partially mock an external method call using powermock

Tags: rspec, junit, tdd, powermock, powermockito

I have 2 classes interacting.
Say `ServiceLayer.class` and `ApiAdaptor.class`:

```
public class ApiAdaptor {
  public String getCountry(String latitude, String longitude) {
    // REST call to api goes here and a the country string is returned
    return country;
  }
}

public class ServiceLayer {
 public String findCountry(int positionId) {
   // some business logic here to get latitude and longitude from postitionId 
   ApiAdaptor api = new ApiAdaptor();
   String country = api.getCountry(latitude, longitude);
   return country;
 }
}
```

Now in the unit test, I want to test only this method `ServiceLayer.findcountry()`, while mocking the internal call to `ApiAdaptor.getCountry(latitude, longitude)`. Is there any way I can do this using Powermock. I have seen similar type of stubing while working with Rspec in Ruby On Rails. I want to do similar testing in my java-SpringMVC project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can use PowerMock to focus only on that method. For example, using PowerMockito specifically, you can write this test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {ServiceLayer.class} )
public class PowerMockitoJan10Test {
    private static final java.lang.String DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE = "USA";

    @Test
    public void testServiceLayerFindCountry() throws Exception {
        ApiAdaptor mock = Mockito.mock(ApiAdaptor.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ApiAdaptor.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.getCountry(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE);

        String country = new ServiceLayer().findCountry(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE, country);
    }
}
```

If you use Spring, it's likely that you need a JUnit runner for that too, so you can use a JUnit rule for PowerMockito instead -- [see this example](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/examples/spring-mockito/src/test/java/org/powermock/examples/spring/mockito/SpringExampleTest.java).

---

**Edit**: this is interesting. When using the rule, it doesn't work indeed unless you add `ServiceLayer.class` to the `@PrepareForTest` list. I used the latest PowerMockito version as of this writing, 1.6.4. Might be worth reporting. In any case, this is how your test will work with Spring:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("mycontext.xml")
@PrepareForTest({ApiAdaptor.class, ServiceLayer.class})
public class PowerMockitoJan10_WithRuleTest {
    private static final String DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE = "USA";

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void testServiceLayerFindCountry() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ApiAdaptor.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(new ApiAdaptor() {
            @Override
            public String getCountry(String latitude, String longitude) {
                return DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE;
            }
        });

        String country = new ServiceLayer().findCountry(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE, country);
    }

}
```

Or, if overriding is a problem, you can mock `ApiAdaptor`:

```
    ...
    ApiAdaptor mock = PowerMockito.mock(ApiAdaptor.class);
    PowerMockito.when(mock.getCountry(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(DESIRED_COUNTRY_VALUE);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ApiAdaptor.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock);
    ...
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing, but when I run the test, the stubbed method is not being called and the completed method runs ... :(

Comment: my annotation  configuration is something like this :
        @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
        @ContextConfiguration
        @PrepareForTest({ServiceLayer.class})

Comment: You were right, it doesn't work just like that when switching to a rule. But I added `ServiceLayer.class` to the list in the annotation and it works well now.

Comment: Just tried it out as an example, and it worked. Here is my code : https://github.com/ishanbakshi/Java-Testing-Adventure/tree/master/src/test/java/com/myapp/mockito

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your code, I'd recommend that you make it more testable by doing dependency injection on your class.

You would have something like that:

```
public class ServiceLayer {
    private ApiAdaptor _api;
    public ServiceLayer(ApiAdaptor api) {
        _api = api;
    }
    [snip]
}
```

Then use `_api` in the rest of your code.

When you need to test this class, and if you have to mock the `ApiAdaptor`, you can just now write :

```
ApiAdaptor mock = Mockito.mock(ApiAdaptor.class);
[Api adaptor behavior mocking]
String country = new ServiceLayer(mock).findCountry(1);
[asserts and all]
```

This removes the need for PowerMockito, its runners and/or rules…

Comment: Thnks for the suggesstions... I am currently doing dependency injection, but i feel at some point in the future i will have to use power mock because i can't keep on declaring class variables... That is why i am looking for a solution specific to power mock or a similar library

Comment: If you start having too much dependencies, maybe it can help to add a class that holds some variables together. Some dependencies may also have more sense as method parameters than class dependencies.